# When building Cordova Android app, build can't find aidl

Tags: android, xml, cordova, build

My phonegap/cordova app using Cordova 3.0 was doing just fine. Then I updated my Android SDK to 4.3 for unrelated reasons (a Titanium app to be more precise), and all of a sudden the build fails, with this error:

```
...
-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] Found 1 AIDL files.
     [aidl] Compiling 1 AIDL files.

BUILD FAILED
/Applications/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:647: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools/aidl" (in directory "/Users/cool/Dropbox/Workspaces/Cordova3Plus/TrueBudgetFree/platforms/android"): error=2, No such file or directory
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
...
```

I've checked the file location, and ...

```
//the aidl executable isn't actually in
Applications/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools/ 
//Instead, it is in a ser
Applications/adt-bundle/sdk/build-tools/[sdk version]/
```

There are subfolders for a few SDK versions (17.0.0 through 19.0.0, and "Android-4.3"). And each of those directories does have the aidl executable in it.

I've tried adding the ../sdk/build-tools folder to my $PATH (Mac), that didn't help.

I'm assuming the builder inserts the version name into the path string, but I can't really tell because I don't understand the inner workings of these build processes. All I can see, sort of, is where the path is referenced/edited.

The build.xml at line 647/653 has this code:

```
<echo level="info">Handling aidl files...</echo>
<aidl executable="${aidl}"
    framework="${project.target.framework.aidl}"
    libraryBinAidlFolderPathRefid="project.library.bin.aidl.folder.path"
    genFolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
    aidlOutFolder="${out.aidl.absolute.dir}">
    <source path="${source.absolute.dir}"/>
</aidl>
```

I've found [this comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlcipher/of0alS-ujy0/dxbY0qqeFJ8J) which suggests that the aidl file gets moved around once in a while with a new SDK.

I've tried reverting to Android SDK 4.2, but that hasn't helped.

What could be the cause here (and more importantly: the solution)?

Answer (score 0):

Ugly answer: I just copied the bloody aidl executable to where build.xml expects it to be.

After trying to build again, the following files also turned out to be expected to reside in platform-tools, even though they are inside build-tools...

aapt
dx

But then dx cannot find dx.jar, so you have to copy lib/dx.jar too...

And that resulted in a successful build. It is scary hacky though.

It also occurred to me I could try to replace the reference to the /platform-tools folder (inside build.xml) with a reference to /build-tools. Haven't tried it yet, and it's equally whacky hacky.

Comment: Did you try running android update project on this code? It sounds like this is just something that you can just clean out.  I've never seen this on the command line, only with Eclipse.

Comment: Hi Joe, I've tried updating the Android SDK. What do you mean precisely by 'running android update project on this code'?

Answer (score 0):

I realize some time has passed, but I just had the same thing happen (not using Cordova, though, but same issue).

Turns out build-tools v19 (`19.0.0`) in **Android SDK Manager** was not really installed, only minor versions after it (`19.0.1-19.0.3`), so the `19.0.0` seems like some sort of partial install and not just missing, strange.
After installing it from the **Android SDK Manager** it started working again.
I'm guessing during some update I accepted to uninstall that revision in favor of 19.0.+